# Html heading element borders fading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm experiencing a strange behavior in my ***h3*** elements

I've set the following style and code

```
.well h3 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    font-size: 22.5px;
    line-height: 42px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
}

<div class="well">
    <h3>Login</h3>
    ...
</div>

<div class="well">
    <h3>Atividade recente</h3>
    ...
</div>

<div class="well">
    <h3>Clans associados</h3>
    ...
</div>
```

As you can see in the screenshots bellow each element has it's border drawn with a different color  (opacity?). The third one is barely visible. I've already inspected each one with Firebug and the style is always the correct as above.

What am I missing?

**Opera Next screenshot**

[image: Opera Next]

**Firefox**

[image: Firefox screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You've created an optical illusion!*

If you put your image into a photo editor and pick colors you'll see that it isn't your border that is changing, it is your background that is changing due the gradient.

The top most element's background color starts at `#BCBCBC` which is signficantly different from the border's color of `#E0E0E0`.  However the bottom element's background is `#E4E4E4`
which is not perceptibly different from `#E0E0E0`.

If you change your elements' background color to something solid and contrasting from `#E0E0E0`, you'll see that your border is working fine.

[image: Contrasting Background]

Comment: LOL, I laughed so much! I fell stupid haha :x I was going nuts trying to figure out what was going on. Thank you!